# Calculating conditional entropy bigrams using NLTK and Kneser-Ney smoothing

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, entropy

I am trying to estimate the conditional entropy of a text source at the bigram level. In order to get a good estimate, I need estimates for the probabilities of bigrams. After doing some reading, it seems that Kneser-Ney smoothing is the most appropriate way to estimate these probabilities.

The nltk module includes Kneser-Ney smoothing, in the `nltk.KneserNeyProbDist` module. However, this only works with trigrams. According to this answer this doesn't work for bigrams ([How to perform Kneser-Ney smoothing in NLTK at word-level for bigram language model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61761215/how-to-perform-kneser-ney-smoothing-in-nltk-at-word-level-for-bigram-language-mo)).

Anyone know how to do this? Maybe using `nltk.lm.KneserNeyInterpolated`. Or would it work if I added a dummy token to the beginning of all my bigrams and used the `nltk.KneserNeyProbDist` module? I'm finding the whole thing very confusing and unclear.